# Is Qt::Thread a library or just a class

Tags: c++, qt

I've a really formal tutor which insists on super correct use of terms. In my assignment I referred to Qt::Thread as a library and he marked me down on it saying that this isn't library but just a class. Now I'm confused and have to ask here, is it just a class or a library?

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as Qt::Thread as far as I know. However, Qt is a C++ GUI library and [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html) is a class that comes with that library. [Take a look here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html) for more on thread support in Qt.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Although I would not call Qt `a C++ GUI library` only. It has much more to offer than a GUI framework.

Comment: @SayemAhmed: true. Qt is not just C++ GUI library. rather, it is `cross-platform application and UI framework with tools designed to streamline the creation of applications for Symbian phones and the Nokia N9 smartphone in addition to desktop platforms, such as Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux`. this is such a long description i keep forgetting, so i prefer saying it to be a `C++ GUI library`. :)

Answer (score 4):

**[QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html)** is a class, so are a number of [others](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html#the-threading-classes).
QT is a library which offers support for enabling builds with or without threading support through the said classes.

**[Refer Documentation:](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html)**

> Qt provides thread support in the form of platform-independent threading classes, a thread-safe way of posting events, and signal-slot connections across threads. This makes it easy to develop portable multithreaded Qt applications and take advantage of multiprocessor machines. Multithreaded programming is also a useful paradigm for performing time-consuming operations without freezing the user interface of an application.
>
> Earlier versions of Qt offered an option to build the library without thread support. Since Qt 4.0, threads are always enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Thread in the Qt namespace (which contains miscellaneous identifiers used throughout the Qt library)

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html

So you can tell him that you where both wrong :)

Qt::Thread = (if it existed) identifier

QThread = Class

Qt = library